# Add Stop function on timer

Tags: javascript

Im creating a timer to display when someone record audio using webrtc.. I have this function working already.What i want to add is stop functionality so whenever the user click stop then the timer also set on timeout. Below is the example code..

```js
// record start time
var startTime;

function display() {
    // later record end time
    var endTime = new Date();

    // time difference in ms
    var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;

    // strip the miliseconds
    timeDiff /= 1000;

    // get seconds
    var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

    // remove seconds from the date
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

    // get minutes
    var minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

    // remove minutes from the date
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);

    // get hours
    var hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24);

    // remove hours from the date
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);

    // the rest of timeDiff is number of days
    var days = timeDiff;

    $(".time").text(days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
    setTimeout(display, 1000);
}

$("input#button").click(function () {
    startTime = new Date();
    setTimeout(display, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Start" />
</div>
<div class="time"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Post reads more like a to do than a question; could you elaborate what the problem is? Perhaps share your current attempt, tell us what part specifically isn't working yet.

Comment: See, `clearTimeout()`

Comment: Hi thanks, I don't have a stop function. could you send me some sample?

Comment: Actually, I want to add a button that when someone clicks it the timer will stop..

Comment: `var startTime;`
`var timer = 1;`
`$("input#button-pause").click(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = 0;
});`

Comment: It's not working..

Comment: Can you send me via fiddle the output..